# Android - Issue with clickableSpan and TextView

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement clickable hashtags in my TextView as below:

```
mTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

Spannable s = (Spannable) mTextView.getText();
CharacterStyle clickableSpan = new MyClickableSpan();
s.setSpan(clickableSpan, startIndex, endIndex, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

this handles onClick for my hashtags as I wanted, but it seems that the other part of the text also listens for onClick events and does nothing.

My question is how to make the non-spannable text parts, delegate the onClick event to the parent view as see in below image.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out my question with this solution but if anyone had a better solution please let me know.

I set OnClickListener for my TextView and in the onClick event I get the parent of my TextView and check if the parent is clickable then perform parent onClick event and if not I recursively get the parent of the parent until I achieve to clickable parent. In this way, hashtags still are clickable with own actions and when clicking another part of the text the onClick event of the parent is performed.

here is the code of how I recursively find clickable parent:

```
private View getParentClickable(View view) {
    try {
        if (((View) view.getParent()).isClickable()) {
            return (View) view.getParent();
        } else {
            return getParentClickable(((View) view.getParent()));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

and then setOnClickListener for my view:

```
mTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
       View parent = getParentClickable(mTextView);
       if (parent != null) parent.performClick();
   }
});
```

Comment: When you click on the clickable span itself it also calls the TextView onClickListener.

If that is not what you want you will need to check whether the span listener was already called recently before delegating the clicks to the parent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this :

```
`SpannableString string = new SpannableString(getString(R.string.some_string));
 ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View textView) {
                //do something
            }`

            @Override
            public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
                super.updateDrawState(ds);
                ds.setUnderlineText(false);
            }
        };

`string.setSpan(clickableSpan, string.length() - 20, string.length(),
                Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        textView.setText(string);
        textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());`
```

Comment: I'm sorry because I think I get bad to explain my issue. please relook to question and give another hint. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**I use the next extension in Kotlin**

```
fun SpannableString.withClickableSpan(
    context: Context,
    clickablePart: String,
    onClickListener: () -> Unit
): SpannableString {
    val clickableSpan = object : ClickableSpan() {
        override fun onClick(widget: View?) {
            onClickListener.invoke()
        }
    }
    val clickablePartStart = indexOf(clickablePart)

    this.setSpan(
        clickableSpan,
        clickablePartStart, clickablePartStart + clickablePart.length,
        Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
    )
    this.setSpan(
        ForegroundColorSpan(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.cyan)),
        clickablePartStart, clickablePartStart + clickablePart.length,
        Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
    )

    return this
}
```

And call it like:

```
val span = SpannableString(text).withClickableSpan(requireContext(), text) {
   onRevisionDateClicked(view)
}
view.movementMethod = LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()
view.setText(span, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE)
view.isClickable = true
```

**OR you can use something like that in Java:**

```
SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("Hello World");
ClickableSpan spanText = new ClickableSpan() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View textView) {
      // do some thing
   }
};

ss.setSpan(spanText, 0, 4, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

textView.setText(ss);
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: @M.SamiAzar Rate this answer if it was helpful

Comment: I think you did not understand my question. I already have done with the clickable span, but I want another part of the text that not hashtag to be no clickable and when I click that area perform parent onClick event